# Where is the "CSS/CODE" about the gap after navbar

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I checked on the css file but I can't get any of it, if I use back the original source code from bootstrap example, it will not have "GAP". I pointing the same bootstrap css file, jquery files and etc

[image: CSS Control? I cant find and relatevent]

I checked on the css file but I can't get it

here is my entire code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="../../favicon.ico">

    <title></title>

    <!-- JQuery  Files -->
    <script src="js/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>


    <!-- Bootstrap Files -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>


<body role="document">

    <!-- Fixed navbar -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Bootstrap theme</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </nav>




    <dic class=""container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>     
                    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="3"></li>
                    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="4"></li>     
                </ol>
                <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                    <div class="item active"><img src="img/s01.jpg" alt="First slide"></div>
                    <div class="item"><img src="img/s02.jpg" style="width:100%;" alt="Second slide"></div>
                    <div class="item"><img src="img/s03.jpg" alt="Third slide"></div>
                    <div class="item"><img src="img/s04.jpg" alt="Second slide"></div>
                    <div class="item"><img src="img/s05.jpg" alt="Third slide"></div>       
                </div>
                <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                </a>
                <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            testing
        </div>

    </div>












</body>
</html>
```

Comment: how to past my entire code over here? it say too long - Raptor

Comment: at least the codes near navbar...

Answer (score 0):

Sure thing, it is in this piece of CSS from the default bootstrap css:

```
.navbar {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
}
```

Just write yourself an override for the **`margin-bottom: 20px;`**

Comment: margin-bottom did not found in CSS, so the solution is write my own margin-bottom:0px !important to overwrite / close the gap....

Comment: @user1493339 That's what I meant--override bootstraps margin with your own. Glad you got it working :)